# How to write a value with jquery based on data-id for a subclass?

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-ext-calendar calendar hideWeek currentDay" data-day="12" data-month="11" data-year="2014" data-modal="#calendarModal">
    <p class="dayNumber">
        <a href="#">12</a>
    </p>
    <p class="weekNumber">
        V 46
    </p><br> 
    <b class="monthViewDayHoliday">
        Foo day
    </b> 
    <b class="monthViewDayName">
        Kurt
    </b>
</div>
```

Now I want to update the `monthViewDayHoliday` with jQuery. How can I do it? I tried the following.

```
$('#modalButtonRow').click(function(event) {
    alert(' foo '+$('.col-sm-1 col-sm-ext-calendar calendar hideWeek currentDay[data-day="12"]').text());
});
```

The above script runs at the right time but it doesn't output the text for the day `12`. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. When listing multiple classes on a single element there should be no spaces between them, and each should be preceded by `.`. Try this:

```
$('.col-sm-1.col-sm-ext-calendar.calendar.hideWeek.currentDay[data-day="12"]').text()
```

As an aside, are you sure you need to specify all those class names to identify this element? I'm sure you could remove a few, or even use an `id` for this instead.